# Excel: Calculate time difference based on max and min values in other cells

Tags: vba, excel, wireshark

I have an excel document based on a Wireshark extract that looks like this:

```
|No.|Time |Source  |Destination|Protocol|Length|Info                      | 
|1  |1.111|10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 13|  
|2  |7.456|10.1.1.2|10.1.1.1   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 13|  
|3  |8.426|10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 14|  
|4  |9.356|10.1.1.2|10.1.1.1   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 13|  
|5  |17.45|10.1.1.2|10.1.1.1   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 14|  
|6  |18.46|10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 14|    
|7  |27.56|10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2   |UDP     |12    |Blah 11 blah blah SeqN: 15|
```

I have extracted the SeqN using a VBA script using RegEX , SeqN can cover 2-6 lines. What I want to do is determine the cycle time. That is the difference in time between the earliest and latest entry for a given SeqN for the first and last entry for a given SeqN (Which can be between 0 and 255).

I'm just not sure how to approach selecting the time variable based on identical entries in another cell.

This is what I am hoping for, SeqN I get using the below script and then an additional column CycleTime

Example output:

```
  SeqN     CycleTime
 SeqN:13     8.245          (or 9.356-1.111)
```

My script for extracting SeqN:

---

```
Sub GetLastDigits()
    Dim Entries As Range, entry As Range
    Dim RegEx As Object, Matches As Object, Match As Object

    Set Entries = Range("G2:G1029")
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With RegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "SeqN: \d+"
    End With

    For Each entry In Entries
        Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(entry)
        If VBA.Left(Matches(Matches.Count - 1), 1) = 0 Then
            entry.Offset(0, 1) = VBA.Right(Matches(Matches.Count - 1), Len(Matches(Matches.Count - 1)) - 1)
        Else
            entry.Offset(0, 1) = Matches(Matches.Count - 1)
        End If
    Next entry
End Sub
```

---

Comment: If SeqN is always the last group of numbers you could extract into another column and then do a pivot table showing min and max time and calculate the difference.